# My try of the Birthday Paradox

Tags: probability, combinations, paradoxes, birthday

I have seen the solution of the paradox on Wikipedia, but before that I tried it out myself. But I got my answer wrong with my approach.

To calculate the probability of no two people in a group of 23 having the same birthday, I divided {the number of ways 23 different days in 365 days can be taken} by {the number of ways 22,21,20,...,2,1 different days can be taken multiplying with the number of ways 23 people can have 22,21,20,...,2,1  birthdays respectively}

I think that would make it a bit harder to understand what I wanted to convey.
And, I find using MathJax a bit tough as I'm new to this. So the link provides the image of what I tried on desmos:[My expression of what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29giW.png)

Comment: Even if I went by your logic, you select $23$ days out of $365$ in numerator but where are you assigning these $23$ days to $23$ people? There are $23!$ ways to do that. I do not understand your denominator at all. Is it not possible that all $23$ have the same birthday? Denominator will have all possible birthday combinations for $23$ people.

Comment: OK I see what you are doing in denominator but it is wrong. Please check $i = 23$ as an example. Why will you choose $23$ birthdays and find only $23$ ways to assign to $23$ people? Isn't it $23!$ ways to assign?

Comment: I know it is wrong. I just couldn't find where I was wrong. Thank you. I get my mistake

Comment: You are welcome. For every number of birthday you choose from $365$, it is going to be a nightmare to find number of ways in which they can be assigned to $23$ people. Take example of $5$ birthdays. Now you have to make sure all $5$ birthdays are assigned  (otherwise it will have cases when you choose $4$ birthdays too) to people and it will require some serious P.I.E. We need to do this for $23$ birthdays :(

Comment: Yeah I got it when you first mentioned that. Thanks again for the effort to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

You have written $$1-\dfrac{{365\choose 23}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{23} i^{23-i}{365 \choose i}}$$ presumably as the probability that there are at least two people sharing a birthday, with $i$ iterating over the possible numbers of distinct birthdays.

Both the numerator and the denominator raise issues.  The numerator is a combination count but if you are counting equally likely events then you want permutations: if there are two people, it is twice as likely that one has a birthday on January 1 and another on January 2 compared with both having birthdays on January 1. So you should have $\frac{365!}{(365-23)!}$ as the numerator.

The other problem is the denominator.  It gives the correct number when $i=1$ of $365$ but not for other $i$.  For example when $i=2$ it gives $2^{22} {365 \choose 2}$ when the number of ways of allocating $23$ people between two days with both used  is $(2^{23}-2){365 \choose 2}$, almost twice as high.  But you do not need a sum over $i$ anyway: the number of equally likely ways of allocating $23$ birthdays (possibly duplicated) over $365$ days is $365^{23}$.

Putting these together means the probability of at least two people out of $23$ sharing a birthday  is $$1-\dfrac{\frac{365!}{(365-23)!}}{365^{23}} \approx 0.5073$$ i.e. just over a half.